# How do I turn the following class into an IObservable?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following classes

```
namespace TickRateEntity
{
    public struct TickRateData
    {
        public double tickrate;
    }

    public class TickRate
    {
        private TickRateData tickRateData;
        //etc
    }
}
```

How do change these classes so that say every n minutes, either TickRate or TickRateData data publishes the double `tickrate`?

Comment: Without knowing how `TickRateData` is populated with data this can't be answered.

Comment: So you want the rate/data published periodically even if it's not changed?

Comment: The value changes every N minutes. But if it doesn't pushing zero is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `tickRateData` is somehow populated, then you could do something like this:

```
public class TickRate : IDisposable
{
    private TickRateData tickRateData;
    private readonly IDisposable _subscription;

    public IObservable<double> Stream { get; }

    public TickRate(double intervalInMinutes)
    {
        var stream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intervalInMinutes))
                               .Select(_ => tickRateData.tickrate)
                               .Publish();

        _subscription = stream.Connect();

        Stream = stream;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ivan - It's being assigned in the constructor so it's ok to be `readonly`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a method with the signature `TickRate GetTickRate()` then this works:

```
int n = 5;
IObservable<double> query =
    from x in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(n))
    let tickRate = GetTickRate()
    select tickRate.tickRateData.tickrate;

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(x => /* do something with `x` */);
```

Otherwise if `TickRate` is being generated some other way the we need to know how to answer this question.

Comment: But  I am confused, that pulls the data not pushes it? I don't quite understand the relationship between Observables and Observers? Where is the Observer in your example? Where is Publish, Where is Subscribe? What if there are multiple subscribers?

Comment: What function does that code live in? How does one tie all the loose ends? Where is OnNext?

Comment: @Ivan - The query pushes the values, but the call to `GetTickRate()` is only there because you haven't said how `TickRate` is populated. If you can provide the right mechanism I can answer the rest of your questions.

Comment: @Ivan - You should avoid using a `Subject`.

Comment: Took your advice and used the chosen answer below. Works great.